# titanium InAppBilling queryInventory return error code -1003 (InAppBilling.IAB_RESULT_VERIFICATION_FAILED)

Tags: android, appcelerator, in-app-billing, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using `ti.inappbilling`  module for in-app billing on Android. I use `titanium sdk` 5.1.2

But when I call it's always returning an error:

```
var InAppBilling = require("ti.inappbilling");
InAppBilling.queryInventory({});
InAppBilling.addEventListener('queryinventorycomplete', function(e) {
if (e.success) {
    purchase = e.inventory.getPurchase(productID);
}else{
    Ti.API.error('queryinventorycomplete: ' + e.responseCode + " - " + responseString(e.responseCode));
    }
});
```

> queryinventorycomplete: -1003 - IAB VERIFICATION FAILED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry it's my fault, I set an undefined PUBLIC_KEY in the setup. now it's correctly

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following things are done.

1.The app is published.

2.The account your are using to test is listed in beta tester list.

3.You accept to be tester in that account.

4.Created product is active.

Also after adding the product it takes a while to take effect. In my case it took two days although it was active.