# Failed to query purchased items inventory (error -1003) - Appcelerator Titanium inAppBilling

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I am making Android application with Appcelerator Titanium. I've added ti.inappbilling module (v. 3.0.2) and everything was working fine (I can make purchases, application is in Google Play) until I want to query inventory (what always returns an error).

I wanted to query already bought items and I did it this way:

```
var runSetup = function() {
     myApp.inAppBilling.startSetup({
        publicKey: myApp.PUBLIC_KEY //this is defined in code
    });
}

var setupComplete = function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            //i did timeout to be sure sure delay is not an issue
            myApp.inAppBilling.queryInventory();
        }, 5000);
    } else {
        alert('Payment Setup FAILED.');
    }
};


myApp.inAppBilling = require('ti.inappbilling');

myApp.inAppBilling.addEventListener('queryinventorycomplete', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(e));
});

myApp.inAppBilling.addEventListener('setupcomplete', setupComplete);

runSetup();
```

As a resposne I always get error -1003 (IAB RESULT VERIFICATION FAILED).

Whole response looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "queryinventorycomplete",
    "source": {
        "bubleParent": true,
        "invocationAPIs": [],
        "apiName": "Ti.Module",
        "__propertiesDefined__": true,
        "_events": {
            "purchasecomplete": {},
            "queryinventorycomplete": {},
            "setupcomplete": {},
        }
    },
    "responseCode": -1003,
    "success": false,
    "bubbles": false,
    "cancelBubble" :false
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [titanium InAppBilling queryInventory return error code -1003 (InAppBilling.IAB\_RESULT\_VERIFICATION\_FAILED)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984802/titanium-inappbilling-queryinventory-return-error-code-1003-inappbilling-iab-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem

check if myApp.PUBLIC_KEY contain your correct key

```
runSetup = function() {
    Ti.API.info('myApp.PUBLIC_KEY  ' + myApp.PUBLIC_KEY);
    myApp.inAppBilling.startSetup({
        publicKey : myApp.PUBLIC_KEY //this is defined in code
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. myApp.PUBLIC_KEY was defined but there was a mistake in string.